# Class, prototype and inheritance in elisp

Tags: elisp, emacs24

Does elisp have the concept of `class` (or) `prototype`? (or) Does elisp use inheritance concept?

Answer (score 3):

More generally, Emacs provides the EIEIO library for object-oriented programming:

> EIEIO ("Enhanced Implementation of Emacs Interpreted Objects") provides
>   an Object Oriented layer for Emacs Lisp, following the basic concepts
>   of the Common Lisp Object System (CLOS).  It provides a framework for
>   writing object-oriented applications in Emacs.

There's a manual dedicated to this:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(eieio)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

I would take good heed of this introductory notice:

> First off, please note that this manual cannot serve as a complete
>   introduction to object oriented programming and generic functions in
>   LISP.  Although EIEIO is not a complete implementation of the Common
>   Lisp Object System (CLOS) and also differs from it in several aspects,
>   it follows the same basic concepts.  Therefore, it is highly
>   recommended to learn those from a textbook or tutorial first,
>   **especially if you only know OOP from languages like C++ or Java**.  If on
>   the other hand you are already familiar with CLOS, you should be aware
>   that EIEIO does not implement the full CLOS specification and also
>   differs in some other aspects which are mentioned below (also *note
>   CLOS compatibility::).

These are useful in that regard:

- [Warp Speed Introduction to CLOS](https://sites.google.com/site/evalapply/guide.html?attredirects=0)
- [Generic Functions and CLOS](http://blog.tymoon.eu/article/268)